# Set DATE_TRUNC week date to Saturday instead of Monday

Tags: sql, presto

I have daily data that I wanted to aggregate to weekly. The date_trunc function sets the default day to Monday. I wanted to start the week date to Saturday.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
DATE_TRUNC('week',(ds + interval '1 day')) - interval '1 day' AS _week
```

This is the DATE_TRUNC function that worked fine but starts Monday:

```
DATE_TRUNC('week', DATE(ds))
```

This is the error I got when using the first code:

```
(SYNTAX_ERROR) line 32:67: mismatched input 'AS'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||', <expression>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you move the single quotes:

```
( DATE_TRUNC('week', (ds + interval '1' day)) - interval '1' day ) AS _week
```

I'm not sure this does what you want (I think you want `'2' day`), but that is a different issue.

Comment: `(SYNTAX_ERROR) line 32:67: mismatched input 'AS'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', 'TO', '[', '||', <expression>`

I still get the same error after moving the single quote as suggested. Not sure why. And yes, I wanted the 2 day :)

Comment: @kenkenhimself . . . I suspect the problem is before this expression in your query.

Comment: Fixed the error under GROUP BY, but I got a different error this time
`(SYNTAX_ERROR) line 4:27: '+' cannot be applied to varchar, interval day to second`

Comment: @kenkenhimself . . . I would say that you have pretty serious problems then.  Why are you storing date/time values as a string and not in a native type?  Why don't you explain this in the query?  What `group by`?   You should ask another question with a full query, sample data, desired results, table layout, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but you can wrap the date_trunc function with the date_add function like below.

```
with my_table as  
( 
select  date('2022-07-05') as my_date
)
select date_add( 'day', -2, date_trunc('week', my_date)) weekof
from my_table
```